# onfocus event on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a menu that is driven by CSS and I have come across a problem for keyboard users. There is no cross browser support for the CSS `:focus` selector, so I am trying to build a jQuery script that will perform the same action.

**HTML menu:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/index.asp" tabindex="12">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/aboutus.asp" tabindex="13">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/whatWeDo.asp" tabindex="14" id="whatWeDo">What We Do</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/whatWeDo1.asp">What we do1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/whatWeDo2.asp">What we do2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/testStudies.asp">Test Studies</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS rules for menu:**

```
#nav ul {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
#nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#nav ul li ul li {
    font-size: 13px;
}
#nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

.showMenu, #nav ul li:hover ul{width:200px; padding:7px; background: #F2F2F2; border:1px solid  #F2F2F2; display: block; position: absolute; left: 85px; top: 30px; }
```

Here is the jQuery code that I am trying to get to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#whatWeDo').focus(function() {
        $(#nav ul li ul).addClass("showMenu");
    });
});
```

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing with the code?

Comment: Try adding quotes around your 3rd selector, eg '#nav ul li ul'.

Comment: remember to have your selector within quotes! `$("#nav ul li ul").ad...`

Answer (score 2):

you forgot quotes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#whatWeDo').focus(function() {
           $('#nav ul li ul').addClass("showMenu");
      });
 });
```

Comment: i have added quotes but still no joy

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten quotes, the jQuery should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#whatWeDo').focus(function() {
       $('#nav ul li ul').addClass("showMenu");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like noted in other answers, surrounding your innermost selector with quotes should do the trick.

Though, I'd like to further point out that it is recommended to bind events using the `on()` function, which was added in jQuery 1.7. Here's how your code would look using `on()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#whatWeDo").on("focus", function() {
        $("#nav ul li ul").addClass("showMenu");
    });
});
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is more info about `on()`.

Comment: I tried the code above and it still does not work. When you hover over the link whatwedo with a mouse the nested list flys out as a sub menu. Im trying to make a function in jquery that gives keyboard users the same effect.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: You have to use the latest version in order to use `on()`. The latest version is 1.7.1, and you can download it from the jQuery site or use [Google's hosted version](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js).

Comment: there has to be something im not doing its still does not work

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks for all your help.
The issue was to do with the CSS style that hid the submenu it over rid the style that the on focus event was trying to do so i had to takle each style at a time.

I also added the id #clientTest to the Test Studies list item so that I could hide the menu once the next link was reached

here is the resulting JQuery code

    $("#whatWeDo").focus(function(){
        $(".sideNav").css("display","block");
        $(".sideNav").addClass("showMenu");
    });
    $("#clientTest").focus(function(){
        $(".sideNav").css("display","none");
     });